# Displaying background processes running by a specific user

Tags: bash, scripts, users, process

I am new in ubuntu linux and I have a little problem: 
I need to write a shell script that displays processes launched in the background by a specific user. Username is a positional parameter. I will be very grateful.

Comment: We don't accept homework assignment.

Comment: Welcome to [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)! Please [edit] your question to show us what you have tried so far and what is the specific part of your given task that you have trouble with. If you don't show that you have put any effort into solving the task, it is unlikely to get an answer here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a homework question.

Comment: You are very very very bad. I need this answer. If I didn.t do this shell script right, I will be expelled. That is very very sad for the next generation :(

Answer (score 1):

This answer explains some of the basics and has some references. You are still going to need to do some research and put some effort to adjust it to your actual needs.

To begin with, let's start with some basic terminology:  Bash is the default command-line interpreter for Ubuntu. This means that bash scripts are composed from your "regular" commands as if you were to execute them by writing each command in the terminal (even start a program), and some features that allow you to automate things or do things repeatably.

Every script has to begin with a definition of what kind of interpreter the operating system should use. For bash it will be: `#!/bin/bash`

The command we will be using is `ps` with some additional parameters.

From `ps` manual page:

```
ps displays information about a selection of the active processes.
If you want a repetitive update of the selection and the displayed
information, use top(1) instead.
```

You can read more about `ps` and the parameters we'll be using here: [PS(1) - Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)

To search an output of a command we will be using `grep`, that lets you search for a specific string or a pattern. More about grep here: [grep(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

The script itself will be very short (the command and the parameter):

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -aux |grep $1
```

Comment: I'm sorry but as you can see this is considered off-topic.  Questions here usually require to show at least some effort or things tried (even if they didn't work or wrong). I gave you this tip which can work very good for you with minor adjustments if needed. Use Ask Ubuntu and try to search for answers if you still have any (one at a time) and the references I added. I promise you everything you need it here.

Answer (score 1):

The next command will show you processes running for `someuser` in background:

```
ps -U someuser -l -H | grep " S "
```

where

```
   -l     Long format.  The -y option is often useful with this.
   -H     Show process hierarchy (forest).
```

`grep " S "` will filter only background processes

For reference, use [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-what-processes-are-running-in-the-background-on-linux/), [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-processes-by-user-names-euid-and-ruid/) and

```
man ps
```

If you want to use it as a script, then create a file:

```
nano procs.sh
```

with the next content:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -U $1 -l -H | grep " S "
```

or the next:

```
ps S -l -u $1
```

Open terminal:

Allow its execution by:

```
chmod +x procs.sh
```

Run it:

```
./procs.sh someuser
```

[image]

[image]

```
user@ubuntu2004:~$ touch procs.sh
user@ubuntu2004:~$ echo 'ps -U $1 -l -H | grep " S "' > procs.sh 
user@ubuntu2004:~$ cat procs.sh 
ps -U $1 -l -H | grep " S "
user@ubuntu2004:~$ chmod +x procs.sh 
user@ubuntu2004:~$ ./procs.sh user
F S   UID     PID    PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S  1000    1677    1634  0  80   0 - 43863 poll_s tty2     00:00:00 gdm-x-session
4 S  1000    1699    1677  4  80   0 - 129191 ep_pol tty2    00:00:08   Xorg
0 S  1000    1753    1677  0  80   0 - 50570 poll_s tty2     00:00:00   gnome-session-b
```

`touch procs.sh` creates an empty file with `procs.sh` file name
`user@ubuntu2004:~$ echo 'ps -U $1 -l -H | grep " S "' > procs.sh` sends `ps -U $1 -l -H | grep " S "` command into `procs.sh` file. It could by added manually using a text editor

About [positional parameters](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-shell-positional-parameters/):

> Positional parameters  are the arguments given to your scripts when it
>   is invoked. It could be from `$1` to `$N`. When N consists of more
>   than a single digit, it must be enclosed in a braces like `${N}`.
>   The variable `$0` is the `basename` of the program as it was called.

`$1` will stand for the first script's parameter
`$2` will stand for the second script's parameter
and so on

In script you call the first argument as a `$1` and use in command as `myscript firstargument`. Bash will replace `$1` with `firstargument` word.

Comment: Can you halp me with the begining? I don t know how to start the program

Comment: You could write a command in some text editor and save it somewhere (Documents, for example). Then open terminal and go to your file location: `cd ~/Documents`. Change its permissions with `chmod`, then run it by typing `./procs.sh yourusername`. I'll edit my question to add some pictures.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you want to help me more, I will be more than tankfull

Comment: Look at updated answer. Maybe you could understand how to start. If not, tell what you don't understand.

Comment: Thank tou for update. It helped me. But can you help me with the rest of the problem? And cand you tell me what is a positional parameter and how can I list the background proces?

Comment: I've already said how to do it. Could you say what is not clear? Couldn't you copy/paste `ps S -l -u $1` command into a text editor, save it and change this file permissions using terminal?

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I didn t see that. Thank you so much for your help. You saved me 

Comment: Can you help me again, please? I shoud do this code in bin/bash. I shoud create a new file, and there I should write what you gave to me? Or shoud I do some changes?

Comment: Look at this very short tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-gskSl4pwQ